# passing a query string to URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to add the page title into the URL.  Just like this site does!  Basically I want to rewrite the url from

```
    www.siteurl.co.uk/project-82
```

to

```
    www.siteurl.co.uk/project/the-title-of-the-project
```

The string that is passed from the php to html file is {PROJECT_TITLE}.  How would I add this in the .htaccess file?  Thanks guys!

EDIT:

This is my .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /project\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule . project-%1? [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^project/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?project_title=$1
```

With the above `.htaccess`, when accessing

> www.siteurl.co.uk/project/the-title-of-the-project

You will in your PHP script have a variable `$_GET['project_title']` containing "the-title-of-the-project".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I meant change it to www.siteurl.co.uk/project/the-title-of-the-project

Comment: Also in the php I have $page->SetParameter ('PROJECT_TITLE', $project_title); but not &_GET['project_title'].  Will that still work?

Comment: Since I don't have your source code, I can't tell you if it'll work. But if you use `$page->SetParameter ('PROJECT_TITLE', $_GET['project_title']`, then it probably will. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi,  Just tried that but with no luck.  It has been playing up all day!  I have edited my post with the .htaccess code i currently have.

Comment: You have not edited your post with your .htaccess, but that doesn't matter. `$page->SetParameter()` is not standard PHP functionality, so I have no idea what it does.

Comment: Sorry!  I am still getting used to the site!  Ok what would be the standard php functionality to pass the project_title to the html view?  Then maybe I can add it in and try to work with that.

Comment: There are no views in PHP as standard. You are probably using a PHP framework.

Comment: You will need the ID of the project because two projects may have same title.

Comment: That is true!  Ah so it is not easily possible then.  That is a shame as it would be very helpful with SEO!

Comment: It wouldn't really be more helpful than StackOverflow's approach. There's nothing wrong in showing the ID of the post.

Comment: How do you keep original query strings as well? `http://example.com/project/something?query=1&otherquery=2`